# PowerShell side-by-side issue EventID 59

Tags: powershell, event-log

I have two machines so far in our organization where I'm getting the side-by-side error when running powershell commands using CMD.exe. We have no issue running this script on all computer models in Win 7. I've tried reinstalling C++ applications to no avail. Any farther help is greatly appreciated.

SxsTrace:

```
=================
Begin Activation Context Generation.
Input Parameter:
Flags = 0
ProcessorArchitecture = AMD64
CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
ManifestPath = C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
AssemblyDirectory = C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
Application Config File = C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.Config
-----------------
INFO: Parsing Application Config File C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.Config.
ERROR: Line 0: XML Syntax error.
ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
End Activation Context Generation.
```

Event Viewer:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        SideBySide
Date:          5/21/2019 1:31:45 PM
Event ID:      59
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      test.domain.com
Description:
Activation context generation failed for "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe".Error in manifest or policy file "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.Config" on line 0. Invalid Xml syntax.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="SideBySide" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49409">59</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-05-21T17:31:45.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>70132</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>test.domain.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.Config</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Applications installed:

```
Name                                             Version
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64) 8.0.59192
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64) 8.0.61000
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64) 8.0.56336
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable   8.0.61001
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x86 Additional Runtime - 14.0.24215   14.0.24215
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x86 Minimum Runtime - 14.0.24215  14.0.24215
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x64 9.0.21022   9.0.21022
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.17    9.0.30729
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64 Additional Runtime - 12.0.40660   12.0.40660
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64 Minimum Runtime - 12.0.40660  12.0.40660
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86 Additional Runtime - 12.0.40660   12.0.40660
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x86 Minimum Runtime - 12.0.40660  12.0.40660
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.6161  9.0.30729.6161
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x64 Additional Runtime - 11.0.61030   11.0.61030
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x64 Minimum Runtime - 11.0.61030  11.0.61030
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x86 Additional Runtime - 11.0.61030   11.0.61030
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 x86 Minimum Runtime - 11.0.61030  11.0.61030
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Additional Runtime - 14.0.23026   14.0.23026
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Minimum Runtime - 14.0.23026  14.0.23026
```

For the registry nothing was done. I thought I'd share it to eliminate troubleshooting steps.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide\Winners\x86|policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt
[image]

Comment: So what, if anything, is actually *in* `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.Config`? The error's pretty much telling you that it can't read that as valid XML. On my machine, the only thing this file contains is some .NET compat settings; PowerShell should work fine even without the file being present at all, but it will not tolerate an invalid file. The Windows loader will barf and refuse to even start a managed process on an invalid .config, since it needs to read it in case there's a manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Even running the powershell.exe program gives me this error. I think we will try to uninstall all of the redistributables and install them again.